# Prevent raising Click event on RadioButton while moving from one to another

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I have a Form with a Panel containig 5 RadioButton

I've only handled the Click event of all RadioButtons.

When I use arrow keys to move from a RadioButton to another, the Click event is raised at each move.

Is it possible to only Select the RadioButton and Click it using SpaceBar?

Comment: That is pretty much have option buttons have worked since the earliest days of Windows.  Changing it would mean they dont work as users have come to expect in your app.

Comment: I've already seen some applications that (on moving) give only an hatched RadioButton and check it using spacebar. If I want this, it is because, at each move on RadioButtons, the UI shows/hides multiple DataGridView, so I think there are too much "changes" in the UI

Comment: That sounds like a custom control of some sort.  If there are 5 and a major action as a result of checking one, why not use a ComboBox - less space used, less code and clearer way to communicate with the user

Comment: @Plutonix You're right, it would be simpler if I use a ComboBox, but I think it's pretty to see all options on the UI at the same time

Comment: You are right they *do* have that going for them. I hate them because they take up so much space.  You know you dont really have to respond to the click/selection - if they are part of a number of options to be selected, evaluate which one when they click a `Do It` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would you use the `Form.KeyDown` event of the parent form and do something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    REM Check if space is the button pressed
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        REM See if a Radio Button has focus to know which was selected
        If RadioButton1.ContainsFocus Then
            RunMyCode(RadioButton1)
        ElseIf RadioButton2.ContainsFocus Then
            RunMyCode(RadioButton2)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Method which executes the code you want run when a radio button is selected
''' </summary>
''' <param name="rdButtona"></param>
Private Sub RunMyCode(ByRef rdButtona As RadioButton)
    REM Check which radio button was selected and execute the apprpriate code
    If rdButtona.Equals(RadioButton1) Then
        MsgBox("Radio Button 1")
    ElseIf rdButtona.Equals(RadioButton2) Then
        MsgBox("Radio Button 2")
    End If
End Sub
```

To prevent the `RadioButton` from being checked, handle the `RadioButton.Click` event and uncheck the `RadioButton` using `radioButton1.checked = false`. If you handle the `RadioButton.CheckChanged` event, `radioButton1.checked = false` will raise another `CheckChanged` event which we don't need. I would also do something there to show which radio button has been selected. In My example I change the text color but you can do whatever you want.

```
   Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    RadioButton2.Checked = False
    ResetColors()
    RadioButton2.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
    RadioButton3.Checked = False
    ResetColors()
    RadioButton3.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    ResetColors()
    RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
End Sub

Private Sub ResetColors()
    RadioButton2.ForeColor = Color.Black
    RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    RadioButton3.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

Of course the code could be simplified, but this is the general idea.

Comment: But this way I have the RadioButton Checked isn't it? And I don't want so. Anyway You give me the hint. I just need to add more code (I hope)

Comment: Yup...shouldn't be too difficult. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, at the moment +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks...Good Luck!! BTW, its prob best to undo your radioButton selected GUI change by using `RadioButton.LostFocus` event. So in my case: `Private Sub RadioButton1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.LostFocus, RadioButton2.LostFocus, RadioButton3.LostFocus
        DirectCast(sender, RadioButton).ForeColor = Color.Black
    End Sub`. This removes the need for another reset method(`ResetColors()`).

Comment: I solved with the code posted as answer but it is thanks to you, so your answer is accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following code runs RadioButtons Click Event only on mouse click (or on spacebar press) and not on arrow keys press. 
It also gives focus to RadioButton selected with Arrow Key

```
Dim HandleRBtnClick As Boolean = True

Private Sub RadioButtons_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles RadioButton1.Click, RadioButton2.Click, RadioButton3.Click, RadioButton4.Click
    If Not HandleRBtnClick Then
        With CType(sender, RadioButton)
            .Checked = False
            .Focus()
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Code for RadioButton Checked (on mouse click or spacebar pressed)
    Me.TextBox1.Text = CType(sender, RadioButton).Name
End Sub

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Left OrElse
        keyData = Keys.Right OrElse
        keyData = Keys.Up OrElse
        keyData = Keys.Down Then

        HandleRBtnClick = False
    Else
        HandleRBtnClick = True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```